# Is there a name for the usage of the present simple tense in situations like "I think" or "I declare" etc?

Tags: grammar, tense

I vaguely remember there was an explanation but I do not know how to find it. Basically, why do we say:
"I think", "I declare", "I expect", "I win" in situations where were clearly do not refer to a habit or general truths, etc.?
THanks a lot

Comment: could you provide examples for some of them? particularly for "I win" because to me it doesn't fit well with the rest...